# What's the correct answer to this question? "Tu ne vas pas à la piscine?"

Tags: questions

> Tu ne vas pas à la piscine ? - (Non - Oui - Si), je déteste la natation.

Comment: Related https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31556/pourquoi-r%C3%A9pondre-si

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Responding to an affirmative question**

> — Tu vas à la piscine ?
>   
> — Oui, j'aime la natation. *(Agreeing — you will go)*
>
> — Tu vas à la piscine ?
>   
> — Non, je déteste la natation. *(Disagreeing — you will not go)*

**Responding to a negative question**

> — Tu ne vas pas à la piscine ?
>   
> — Non, je déteste la natation. *(Agreeing — you will not go)*
>
> —  Tu ne vas pas à la piscine ? 
>   
> — Si, j'aime la natation. *(Disagreeing — you will go)*

---

Note that all of these are the informal style of asking questions (i.e. like declarative sentences but with a rising intonation).

A less informal way is with the *est-ce que* structure:

> Est-ce que tu ne vas pas à la piscine ?

The most formal way is by inversion:

> Ne vas-tu pas à la piscine ?

(**Thanks to @LukeSawczak for his edits**)

Comment: (I liked your answer so decided to edit it to add more detail rather than start a new one — apologies if the changes are more significant than intended)