# Can you help me Invert the sentences?

Tags: inversion

Please complete the sentences using inversion?

EXEMPLES
Qu'est-ce que tu aimes faire le soir?
**Qu'aimes-tu faire le soir?**
Tu aimes sortir le soir?
**Aimes-tu sortir le soir?**

-Qu'est-ce que vous aimez faire ensemble?

-Tu préfères rester à la maison ou sortir?

-Vous jouez à des jeux vidéo?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: I would suggest you do your homework alone... especially as this one seems very easy, I don't know what you don't understand there?

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that this type of questions risks to get closed. See here [https://french.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask] a guide how to properly (re)formulate your question.

To answer on your own your question, the corresponding theory can be found for instance here:

https://www.dummies.com/languages/french/how-to-form-a-question-in-french-using-inversion/

https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/inversion/

There are also a lot of question in FSE which cover similar topics. See also the question here

[What's the correct answer to this question? "Tu ne vas pas à la piscine?"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30494/whats-the-correct-answer-to-this-question-tu-ne-vas-pas-%c3%a0-la-piscine/30496#30496)

The following is but an incomplete coverage.

First of all, note that there is a space between the letter and the question mark in French writing system. That is

> Puis-je ? Can I?

> Qu'est-ce que tu aimes faire le soir ? -> Qu'aimes-tu faire le soir ?

> Qu'est-ce que vous aimez faire ensemble ? -> Qu'aimez-vous faire ensemble ?

> Vous voulez partir. -> Voulez-vous partir ?

Note also the hyphen (tirer in French nomenclature) between verb and pronoun.

As a rule of thumb:

**Subject+Verb (affirmative)=> Verb+Subject (inverted question).**

> Il mange de la soupe.->Mange-t-il de la soupe ?

Note the *t* inserted for euphony here.