# Questions about "Avez-vous fait?"

Tags: grammaire, expressions

Can *avez-vous fait* mean did you do, have you done since present tense is used with one type in French.

*Avez vous fait un service civique* = did you do civil service, have you done civil service.

Is it correct and can it mean something else also?

Comment: This is not present, it's "Passé composé". "Avoir auxiliary" is in the present tense, while "faire" verb is in the past principle. You French sentence is correct, except for the missing  hyphen: should be "Avez-vous fait un service civique".

Comment: Merci monsoir . .

Comment: Monsieur instead of monsoir:-)!

Comment: Merci oui. Je parle un peu francias.

Comment: T'inquiète (don't worry)! Keep on learning and posting questions in FSE whenever you encounter an issue.

Comment: For instance I mentioned the the so-called MRS-DR-VANDERTRAMPP mnemonic rule. There are several related questions to it!

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30367/what-is-the-difference-between-the-verb-sortir-being-conjugated-with-%c3%aatre-or-a/30373#30373

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16789/dr-and-mrs-vandertrampp ; https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29539/laccord-du-participe-pass%c3%a9-dans-les-temps-compos%c3%a9s/29543#29543

Comment: FSE is a great place to improve your French, but as the saying goes "C'est en forgeant qu'on devient forgeron (i.e practice makes perfect):-)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Avez-vous fait?

is the inverted-form of a French question.

It may convey

> Did you do and Have you done?

Note the hyphen.

A more colloquial way would be

> Vous avez fait (e.g. les devoirs) ? (with rising intonation)
> or
> Est-ce que vous avez fait (e.g. les devoirs) ? (with the set turn *est-ce que*

[See https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30494/whats-the-correct-answer-to-this-question-tu-ne-vas-pas-%c3%a0-la-piscine/30496#30496 and references therein.]

**Vous avez fait** is the second person of the plural (or the so-called form of vouvoiement) of the passé composé (present perfect). It is the usual choice when one needs to convey the English present perfect or the simple past.

You take the auxiliary avoir and you conjugated in present and you add the past participle (participe passé) of the verb faire (i.e. fait). Note that there are several verbs that take être as auxiliary verb for the compound tenses construction. Googling the so-called MRS-DR-VANDERTRAMPP mnemonic rule which can be quite helpful when you are a beginner.

There are several past tenses in French. A beginner should learn the three most common ones (Passé composé, imparfait, plus-que-parfait). There are some literary tenses like Passé simple (je fis!) but you should not worry too much about them, at least initially. Thery are only found in books and barely used (if not at all) in oral French.

I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: I may misunderstand that answer, but "avez-vous fait" is correct, when "vous avez fait ...?" is used at oral, but incorrect, and seems odd when written.

Comment: @Ouch42 There are three types of Yes/No questions: 1) By turning a statement into a question; 2) By using est-ce que; 3) By changing the order of the words in the sentence.

Comment: @Ouch42  Il est arrivé. Il est arrivé with rising intonation). Est-ce qu'il est arrivé? Est-il arrivé (inversion; the most formal)?

Comment: @Ouch42 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vous+%C3%AAtes+arriv%C3%A9s+%3F%2Con+est+arriv%C3%A9s+%3F&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvous%20%C3%AAtes%20arriv%C3%A9s%20%3F%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20est%20arriv%C3%A9s%20%3F%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Ouch42 See https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30494/whats-the-correct-answer-to-this-question-tu-ne-vas-pas-%c3%a0-la-piscine/30496#30496

Comment: I'm a native french speaker. Of course, if asking my children if they did there homework, I would say "Vous avez fait vos devoirs?", but the correct sentence should be "Avez-vous fait vos devoir?". I thought you were saying that "Avez-vous" was incorrect. If not, I misunderstood your answer.
Writing to my boss, for instance, I would use "Avez-vous fait...?", for sure.

Comment: @Ouch42 I mean in colloquial speach. I didn't say that the inversion is incorrect. All the forms are correct depending on the setting. Even the rising intonation is not incorrect strictly speaking. We can say that it is a more relaxed form of questioning.

Comment: The inversion tends to disappear every day a bit more in day-to-day speach or even written texts...